# How i can generate a valid SP XML file for SAML2?

Tags: apache, saml-2.0, adfs, shibboleth

i don't know implement SAML2 protocol for my custom SP service, and i've some difficults...

I have tried this;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" entityID="http://www.mydomain.ext/#/secure">
  <SPSSODescriptor WantAssertionsSigned="true" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
   <AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="http://www.mydomain.ext/#/" isDefault="true"/>
    <KeyDescriptor>
     <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <ds:X509Data>
       <ds:X509Certificate>
        {my_x509_certificate_generated}
       </ds:X509Certificate>
      </ds:X509Data>
     </ds:KeyInfo>
    </KeyDescriptor>
   <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity</NameIDFormat>
  </SPSSODescriptor>
 </EntityDescriptor>
```

I need make it for send xml file to the IDP. What miss for make a valid SP xml file?, Thank's

Answer (score 3):

The XML you attached is an SP metadata which describes the SP properties - ID, certificate, binding support, etc...
I suggest you get more familiar with SAML before getting into actual coding or configuration.

Here are some good resources:

https://github.com/jch/saml

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0

In case you'r implementing your SP with JAVA, here are some good libraries you can use:
OneLogin's SAML Java Toolkit - https://github.com/onelogin/java-saml

Okta SignIn widget - https://github.com/okta/okta-signin-widget

LastPass SAML SDK for Java - https://github.com/lastpass/saml-sdk-java

Dead Simple SAML 2.0 Client - https://github.com/coveo/saml-client

pac4j - http://www.pac4j.org/docs/clients/saml.html

Comment: Thank Tomer Sela for your apport. After configure my SP, i can see my SP Metadata file in the URL "http://www.mydomain.ext/Shibboleth.sso/Metadata". The new problem, is when i put the credentials on the IDP login, this redirect again to IDP and display error message. Not work the redirect to my SP to create a session. Is possible that is needed configure more things on IDP?

Comment: What is the error you see? here are few things to check -
Does your metadata have the right ACS URL? this is where the IDP know where to redirect the user for authentication in the SP; Did you configure your SP to use the same binding as the IDP use for transferring the SAML response message? (according to your metadata, this is HTTP-POST); Have you updated the SP with the IDP certificate?

Comment: No, i see a custom error page view. This is the result of the metadata file path => https://pastebin.com/raw/r39PHz8c . The federation with the IDP is correct. Can i redirect the post received data with Apache?¿ Thank's!

Comment: You can perform the Post binding with Apache or any other web-server. One way to do so is by returning a HTML form with a script that will automatically post the form to the ACS url - http://saml.xml.org/wiki/idp-initiated-single-sign-on-post-binding

Comment: Thank you Tomer Sela. I understand that the IDP contains the login form, after complete, The IDP send POST data to my SP. The Shibboleth service handle the response and should redirect to apache service, right?. I would like to know which data receive the SP service before to redirect. My website haven't got any Form, only the view. Is it neccesary make a Form on SP and change POST url without Shibboleth?