# How to Generate SP XML for Spring Security SAML Plugin

Tags: grails, adfs, idp, spring-security-saml2

I am coding in grails 3.3.9 and am using the Spring Security SAML Plugin in order to use SSO with Microsoft Active Directory 2012. This plugin requires the idp xml and the sp xml. I have ADFS (AD Federation Services) as my idp (and I figured out how to get the idp xml for that) and now I need to know how to generate the sp xml. The plugin docs didn't provide a guide for it. I am assuming the sp is my grails application? How do I generate sp.xml with my idp as ADFS?

Comment: check this if it's helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46099042/how-i-can-generate-a-valid-sp-xml-file-for-saml2

Comment: @RahulMahadik Not sure if I completely understand. So do I need some type of external application to get the service provider metadata? I could not find that info in the documentation for the [Spring Security SAML Plugin](https://jeffwils.github.io/grails-spring-security-saml/)